# global variable not changed

Tags: javascript

I declared two variables globally, first one is input text field and second is select field. When I change the option field, the local variable values set is to the global variables. But global variables didn't got the values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id1;
var opt1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#opt").change(function() {
        id = $("#id").val();
        opt = $("#opt").val();
        id1 = id;
        opt1 = opt;
        if(!id=="" && !opt=="") {
            //alert(id);
        } else { }
     });
</script>
```

Comment: After indenting your code, I see that you're missing a closing parenthesis ..

Comment: @Rob W - Not only that, but when it's all on one line, the commented out `alert()` will cause the rest of the line after it to be commented out as well. Bit of a mess, really.

Comment: the code fragment is broken, because you inlined a comment.

Comment: closing parenthesis is there,it's missing in question.

Comment: Follow [this](http://jsfiddle.net/88pawankumarjha/kFWBa/) link to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You've got _four_ global variables, not two: `id` and `opt` were not declared with `var` at all, so they are automatically created with global scope when you assign values to them, they are not local to your change handler function. The `id1` and `opt` variables are global because they were declared with `var` outside of any functions. Also, don't say `!id==""`, say `id!=""`.

Comment: _"But global variables didn't got the values."_ - Assuming you are talking about `id1` and `opt1`, in the above code all you do is assign  a value to them, you don't ever try to use the value, so how do you know the values didn't get set? Please show the part of your code that tries to use the values from these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is down to the "minimised" formatting you've tried to use; it makes your code impossible to read, and therefore you've missed the fact that you're missing a closing bracket. Reformatting the code will help you spot this. In addition you also used a `//` comment, in the middle of it which results in the rest of the line being commented out, meaning that your brackets are even more out of sync.

The answer is to write your code in a properly indented format, rather than trying to put it all onto one line. If you want it minimised, don't do it yourself; there are tools that can do that for you, and only do it for the copy you put online, not the copy you're testing with; the version you work with and test with should be properly formatted.

Comment: Make sure to check the ''javascript error console''. It should report about missing paranthesis etc.